# Using substitution to prove $\int^a_0f(x)\,dx=\int^a_0f(a-x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I was given the following question:

Given the $f$ is a function such that the integrals exist, use the substitution $u=a-x$ to show that
$$
\int^a_0f(x)\,dx=\int^a_0f(a-x)\,dx
$$

I belive I've solved the question by using transformations as follows:
$$
\int^a_0f(x)\,dx=\int^0_{-a}f(-x)\,dx=\int^a_0f(a-x)\,dx
$$
I would appreciate it if somebody explained to me how I would achieve the same solution using the substitution $u=a-x$.

Comment: You did 2 substitutions of $ x \rightarrow -x$ and $ -x \rightarrow a-x$, so essentially you could have combined it into just 1 substitution of $ x \rightarrow a - x$ which is what you asked for. Can you figure this out now? (If no, explain what is confusing to you)

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you - yes that makes sense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered in the first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $u = a-x$. Then $x = a-u$, so $dx = d(a-u) = -du = (-1)\;du$.

When $x=0$, we have $u=a-0 = a$

When $x=a$, we have $u = a - a = 0$.

So substitution gives

$$\int_{x =0}^{x=a} f(x)\;dx = \int_{\underbrace{u=a}_{x=0}}^{\overbrace{u=0}^{x=a}}f(\underbrace{a-u}_x)\underbrace{(-1)\;du}_{dx}$$
Since $\int_r^s =-\int_s^r$, we may swap limits and change sign to get the desired result
$$\int_0^a f(x)\;dx = \int_0^a f(a-u)\;du$$
Since the name of the variable of integration is irrelevant, this is the same as $$ = \int_0^a f(a-x)\;dx$$